# How do I get my function definitions to work in Swift 3.1 if they worked in Swift 1.1?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

I was using Swift 1.1 and I just upgraded to Swift 3.1, and this extension below no longer works. I am getting the compiler errors marked with notes below. Is there an easy way to fix my syntax? I tried converting the code using xcode's built-feature but that only seemed to apply to the classes, and not this extension.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


extension UIView {
/**
Set x Position

:param: x CGFloat
by DaRk-_-D0G
*/
func setX(#x:CGFloat) {  //Expected parameter name followed by ':'
    var frame:CGRect = self.frame
    frame.origin.x = x  //Use of unresolved identifier 'x'
    self.frame = frame
}
/**
Set y Position

:param: y CGFloat
by DaRk-_-D0G
*/
func setY(#y:CGFloat) {   //Expected ',' separator
    var frame:CGRect = self.frame
    frame.origin.y = y  //Use of unresolved identifier 'y'
    self.frame = frame
}
/**
Set Width

:param: width CGFloat
by DaRk-_-D0G
*/
func setWidth(#width:CGFloat) {   //Expected ',' separator
    var frame:CGRect = self.frame
    frame.size.width = width  //Use of unresolved identifier 'width'
    self.frame = frame
}
/**
Set Height

:param: height CGFloat
by DaRk-_-D0G
*/
func setHeight(#height:CGFloat) {   //Expected ',' separator
    var frame:CGRect = self.frame
    frame.size.height = height   //Use of unresolved identifier 'width'
    self.frame = frame
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the modern language like swift which is improving day by day, not stabilized yet it's quite common for this kind of changes to happen. In this evolution process, lot's of things will be added and removed. The same thing happened with **#** mark. It's there initially. But now it's removed. Remove that # and everything will work as expected.